# Spark Scala error while loading BytesWritable, invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, header, sbt

Using `sbt package` I have the following error

> Spark Scala error while loading BytesWritable, invalid LOC header (bad signature)

My code is

```
....
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
......

object Test{
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf) // the error is due by this 
    ...... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Pls re-load your JARs and / or library dependencies as they might be corrupted while building jar through sbt - could be issue with one of their update. Second alternative is that you have too many temp files open, check your 4040-9 ports on master if there are any jobs hanging and kill them if so, you can also check how increase open files you have on linux:`/etc/security/limits.conf` where `hard nofile` ***** and `soft nofile *****` then reboot and `ulimit -n ****`

Answer (score 0):

I was using spark-mllib_2.11 and it gave me the same error. I had to use version 2.10 of Spark MLIB to get rid of it.

Using Maven:

```
<artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
```